# Increase id with 1

Tags: javascript

I want the following: when the user is clicking on the button, the id must be increased with 1. Now I uses a familiar function for unique id's for my rows and works correctly. Now I have used the same snippet of code for unique input fields, but this doesn't work. Also it's strange that the following code does his work correctly on the name attribute.

```
    clone.find('#dsmeta_image_caption').prop('name', 'dsmeta_image_caption[' + row.length + ']'); // we now need to set the new ID for the row - ID's cannot be duplicated. This again will use the row.length
```

So what I want is to increase each field id with 1.

Code JS:

```
function create_row_event(event) {
    // Declared variable
    var row = jQuery('tbody tr.row');
    var clone = row.last().clone(true);

    // Find the cloned fields and reset the values of it
    clone.find('input[type=text], text, textarea, select, input.upload_image').val(''); // Reset the values
    clone.find('.preview_image').attr('src', ''); // Reset the values


    row.parent('tbody.ui-sortable').append(clone); // Append the new row to the body
    clone.prop('id', 'repeatable-[' + row.length + ']'); // we now need to set the new ID for the row - ID's cannot be duplicated. This again will use the row.length
            clone.find('input#dsmeta_image_caption').prop('id', '[' + row.length + ']');


}
```

Here you can see the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Caspert/ttgMc/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find('#id')` operation won't work because a duplicate IDs is involved there. And as soon as there are duplicate IDs in a document you can't expect ID-based selectors/filters to work as they should.

Use e.g. `find('input:text')` instead and it will work.